# Is `-ftree-slp-vectorize` not enabled by `-O2` in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, simd, auto-vectorization

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

It says "-ftree-slp-vectorize: Perform basic block vectorization on trees. This flag is enabled by default at -O2 and by -ftree-vectorize, -fprofile-use, and -fauto-profile."

However it seems I have to pass a flag explicitly to turn on SIMD. Did I mis undertand something here? It is enabled at `-O3` though.

https://www.godbolt.org/z/1ffzdqMoT

Comment: I assume GCC is changing this because of folklore than `-O3` is "too aggressive" and/or often not faster. Clang enables auto-vectorization at `-O2`, so GCC before 12 looked bad by comparison if people benchmark at `-O2`.  Simple loops on modern CPUs benefit significantly from SIMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `-ftree-slp-vectorize` not enabled by `-O2` in GCC?

Yes and no. It depends on the version of the compiler.

> From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

You have linked to the latest version of documentation. It applies to the version that is currently under development, which at the moment is version 12.

> However it seems I have to pass a flag explicitly to turn on SIMD.
>
> https://www.godbolt.org/z/1ffzdqMoT

Your example uses GCC version 11.

> Did I mis undertand something here?

You read the wrong version of documentation, or used wrong version of compiler and hence your assumption didn't hold.

Comment: ha that's it! I didn't see terms like `latest` or `current` in the url so I didn't know the doc is versioned. But thanks to you I looked into it and found `https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html` is what I am looking for